# difference between customobject and psobject?

Tags: object, powershell

This is a simple question, more theoretical than anything.

What's the real difference between a custom object and a PSObject in Powershell ?
Why and when would you create them ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PSCustomObject arrived with PowerShell 3.0. I woulddefine it as 'refined version' of PSObject as it addresses a couple of annoyances with PSObject including display order (PSCustomObject keeps the order you specified), some performance enhancements.

Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012773/difference-between-psobject-hashtable-and-pscustomobject) to more discussion on this.

Comment: Some syntactic shortcuts were introduced in V3, but PSCustomObject was there in V2.  If you try: (new-object PSObject).GetType().FullName, you'll see the same thing in V2 and V3 - it's PSCustomObject.

Comment: Thanks @JasonShirk for pointing that out. I assumed question was about the new [PSCustomObject] 'accelerator' vs v2 version of [PSObject] when I said it arrived in v3.

Answer (score 1):

PSObject is used as a wrapper object for all objects in PowerShell.  This includes custom objects.  If you create a PSCustomObject, you're really just creating a PSObject under the covers.

Comment: There is also a difference when you cast a hashtable to a PSCustomObject - that creates a, well, custom object where each key/value pair becomes a property/value pair. Casting a hashtable to a PSObject is a no-op.