# Is there a way to get-content from a specific NoteProperty in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, object

So I have created 2 objects called $Row1 and $Row2 which are populated with values in the following manner

```
$Row1 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $name
$Row1 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Age -Value $age

$Row2 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $name
$Row2 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Age -Value $age
```

I'm now looking for a way to access only the **age** value with Get-Content.

Comment: I think $Row1.Age and $Row2.Age would do it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this is that it would be suffice with writing $Row1.(TheNotePropertyName you want to access)

eg.

```
$Row1.Age
$Row1.Name
$Row2.Name
```

This works both for PScustomobjects and Psobjects. The difference between these are found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012773/difference-between-psobject-hashtable-and-pscustomobject).

Comment: Yes, on _accessing_ properties with `.`, the [member-access operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#member-access-operator-), PowerShell doesn't distinguish between type-native properties and `NoteProperty` properties added via PowerShell's [ETS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_types.ps1xml). While there is no real difference between `[pscustomobject]` and `[psobject]`, the latter should really be considered an invisible helper type that is not to be used directly.