# Using the exit statement breaks the output in some cases. Is there a reason for this or is it a bug?

Tags: powershell

I need help understanding a strange output behavior when using the exit statement and `pscustomobject`.

Example, script.ps1:

```
'hello'
[pscustomobject]@{'foo'='bar'}
'world'
exit 123
```

Calling the script: `powershell -file script.ps1`

Only `hello` will be returned. Versions 5.1 and 7.1 both behave like this. Can it be explained, or is this something for the github guys to fix?

Edit, based on comments: Running it from within Powershell, it works as expected. Calling PowerShell with `-Command .\script.ps1` it also works (the exit code is gone, though).

It is this combination that breaks the output: Using the `exit` statement and calling PowerShell with `-File`.

Thanks

Comment: Can you try to wrap it in the *sub-expression* operator? `$([pscustomobject]@{'foo'='bar'}) | Out-Default`. I think I have an idea, just wanna confirm.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala, i just tested your theory and it does work, but then i removed the `$()` and it still worked as ```[pscustomobject]@{'foo'='bar'} | Out-Default```, so its as if the the expression is never being sent to stdout?

Comment: Why dont you assign the pscustomobject to a variable? $mytest = [pscustomobject]@{'foo'='bar'} and everything runs fine.  $myTest = [pscustomobject]@{'foo'='bar'}
[console]::writeline($myTest) also runs fine

Comment: This almost certainly has to do with `pscustomobject` vs `psobject` (it works with psobject), i just cant figure out why yet! Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50196654/16106482) link to learn more about them. 
> PSCustomObject isn't an object type per se – it's a process shortcut.

Comment: @otter, to summarize, the call to `exit` beats the pipeline output to the formatting system; which PowerShell bases the execution off of. This is why using just the sub-expression alone should work, but so would any formatting cmdlets. Take a look at mklements answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43691123/14903754). So yes, it doesn't make it doesn't make it to *stdout*.

Comment: I ran into this issue before where my `Read-Host` kept coming before my `PSCustomObject`.

Comment: You are right! Putting sleeps of a second between each line worked fine (lower than a second failed). Can't say I'm a fan of this behaviour but i understand it. Can you put it in as the answer so @palansen can accept it?

Comment: Yeah man, I'm not fan of that either lol. Ehh, I'll just flag it as a duplicate.

Comment: Inserting a sleep seems to "fix" it, but it differes from what mklement0 talks about. In this case, all objests are emitted to the pipeline - so they should be processed in correct order.

And keep in mind: It only happens when you call powershell from an external application - and using -File and the exit statement.

Comment: You're calling a file, not the commands individually. PowerShell.exe will not change it's rules just because it's being called from cmd.exe.

Comment: What rule is that? mklement0 is talking about emitting objects + calling Write-Host, where objects are displayed out of order. It is very different from this problem - where objects are not displayed/returned at all - when the script is executed under a specific condition.

Comment: Please re-read his explanation and not just the code snippet, that was just his examples of what was happening. Not the actual answer itself.

Comment: You are right. And it seems that calling exit within 300 ms of outputting the pscustomobject just terminates the script without outputting anything. I'm almost happy now. Thanks. :)