# Powershell: Command (getType) not returning any output to terminal under certain condition

Tags: powershell, logging, types, output

I have the following code:

```
# Much more efficient than using an Array and +=
$ArrayList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
[void]$ArrayList.Add([PSCustomObject]@{ Username = 'Scissile'; Path = 'C:\Users\Scissile'; Type = 'User'})
[void]$ArrayList.Add([PSCustomObject]@{ Username = 'Mufti'; Path = 'C:\Users\Mufti'; Type = 'User'})
[void]$ArrayList.Add([PSCustomObject]@{ Username = 'Hijinks'; Path = 'C:\Users\Hijinks'; Type = 'User'})
[void]$ArrayList.Add([PSCustomObject]@{ Username = 'Chad'; Path = 'C:\Administrators\Chad'; Type = 'Admin'})
$ArrayList

# Convert an Array to an ArrayList
$NormalArray = 2,4,6,8,10,12,14
$Transformed = [System.Collections.ArrayList]$NormalArray
$Transformed.getType()
```

The terminal outputs the following:

```
D:\Dev\Powershell> d:\Dev\Powershell\Snippets\PSCustomObjects.ps1

Username Path                   Type
-------- ----                   ----
Scissile C:\Users\Scissile      User
Mufti    C:\Users\Mufti         User
Hijinks  C:\Users\Hijinks       User
Chad     C:\Administrators\Chad Admin
```

I can't figure out why `$Transformed.getType()` is not returning any output to the console. If I comment out `$ArrayList` on line 7, I do get the output of $Transformed.getType():

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     ArrayList                                System.Object
```

Can someone explain this behavior? Why can't I get output from `$Transformed.getType()`?

Comment: This is due to powershells formatting system. In other words, `$ArrayList` beats `$Transformed.getType()` to the punch and it never gets sent to stdout. You can work around it by piping to a format cmdlet, or specifically specifying to go out to the console with either `Out-Host`, or `Out-Default` (*the invisible cmdlets ran after (almost) every command*): `$ArrayList | Out-Default`. There's a nicely explained answer by Mklement that I will try to find and comment here for detailed info on this subject.

Comment: Oops...I meant: `$Transformed.getType() | Out-Default`, not `$ArrayList`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information. That makes a lot more sense to me. I would really appreciate if you could find the answer you referenced and post it so I can read more about the subject. I will also accept your explanation if you respond with an answer. Thanks again.

Comment: No worries man, will probably just flag as duplicate. Also, I found it! See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43691123/14903754).

Comment: @AbrahamZinala   


I am kind of scared after reading the question you linked:  

"From the outside, when calling the PowerShell CLI (powershell -file ""): **Actual data loss may occur**"   

See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69425902/using-the-exit-statement-breaks-the-output-in-some-cases-is-there-a-reason-for    

Can things get f'd up by piping to Out-Host or Out-Default?  

Am I going to have to add sleep commands to my script if I'm calling it externally?

Comment: Nah bro, read the second bullet. It's just repeating (*for the most part*), that it can happen as well when calling powershell's cli from the outside. No **real** data loss occurs besides the output that doesn't happen, if that makes sense? The only real issue when piping to `Out-Host`,  is that you lose the integrity of the actual object as it gets sent directly to the *host*.

Comment: Actually, @AbrahamZinala - the answer you linked to in your comment is about a different original problem, although both problems can be solved - imperfectly - by forcing to-host output with `Out-Host`, for instance. Jay, `Out-Host` invariably prints directly to the display, which means that the output cannot be captured or redirected.

Comment: Jay, I've clarified the statement re data loss in the linked answer: basically, when you call PowerShell _from the outside_, data loss can occur if you have pending table output and exit the script / command with `exit`. `Out-Host` then actually _prevents_ data loss (the outside world _does_ see `Out-Host` output as _data_). _Inside_ PowerShell, however, the price of using `Out-Host` (as well as `Out-Default`, which shouldn't be called directly, however) is the inability to capture or redirect the output, as stated. /cc @AbrahamZinala